# Isomorphic React with Webpack's resolve.root option

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, isomorphic-javascript

My React app uses requires relative to the root of my JS file using Webpack's `resolve.root`. I.e. my file structure contains the following:

```
components
  App.react.js
containers
  AppContainer.react.js
```

In AppContainer.react.js, I have:

```
import App from 'components/App.react';
```

This works client-side. Now I'm trying to make it isomorphic. If I require AppContainer.react.js in my server.js, it says `components/App.react` isn't found. Node is trying to require `containers/components/App.react.js`, which doesn't exist. How can I make Node require relative to a given directory?

Edit: My directory structure looks like this:

```
css/
html/
js/
  components/
    App.react.js
  containers/
    AppContainer.react.js
  main.js <- requires AppContainer
public/
server/
  server.js <- requires AppContainer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use https://github.com/halt-hammerzeit/universal-webpack.  This will let you keep your same webpack config (eg. `resolve.root` and any aliases) and additionally help get you moving towards server side rendering. The usage docs give a pretty good example of how to get this up and running.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to use this babel-plugin: `babel-plugin-module-resolver`,

then change your .babelrc as follow:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["module-resolver", {
      "root": ["."],
      "alias": {
        "components": "./components"
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

then you can require your component in your server.js `import App from 'components/App.react';`

Comment: That wouldn't work because it doesn't scale well, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Why doesn't this scale well?

Comment: Nevermind, for some reason, I thought I had to add each directory to .babelrc. Since it's just the top level directories, this should probably work.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried

```
import App from '../components/App.react';
```

Answer (score -1):

Where is your server.js file?  If it is in the same directory as your 'containers' folder you can do `./components/App.react`.

Otherwise, you can use `..` to get back as far as you need to to find your files.

```
Examples (relative to server.js):
./ -> current directory
../ -> up one directory
../../ -> up two directories
etc..
```

Comment: I want to use requires relative to the root of my Javascript files.

Comment: What does your entire directory structure look like?

Comment: I updated the question to include my entire directory structure.

Comment: import App from '../js/components/App.react'; should do it

Answer (score -1):

Based on your directory structure..

```
import App from '../js/containers/AppContainer.react';
```

is what you want.

Comment: As I stated in the question, I want all paths relative to the root of my JS files.